# python open web pages in batch mode

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, web

System: Dell, Windows 7

Setup: PyCharm 5.0.2 + anaconda 2.7.11-0

Limitations: My preference would be to use a Mac, but my work requires me to use a Windows machine. I am familiar with the unix/linux terminals but unfamiliar with the windows command prompt.

Problem: I would like to open multiple webpages that use a Bing (or Google) search on a list of keywords. (I have entered into a new field and need to look up a hundreds of unknown terms. I am too lazy to manually do the search for each term.)

My attempts:

1. I have not been successful in finding an application that does Bing or Google searches in batch mode. Thus, I have decided to write my own script.
2. I recalled seeing that webpages could be rendered directly in the jupyter with the HTML() from IPython.display:

   ```
   # import modules
   from IPython.display import HTML

   # create the list of keywords
   keys = ['grumpy+cat','garfield+cat','basement+cat']

   # loop through each key and display the search webpage
   for k in keys:
       HTML('<iframe src=https://www.google.com/search?q='+k+' width=700 height=350></iframe>')
   ```

Alas, nothing happens. I did check this:

```
HTML('<iframe src=https://www.google.com/search?q='+k[0]+' width=700 height=350></iframe>')
```

And that seems to be fine, but I need automation.

3. I moved on to a combination of input file, python command generating script, and batch script (to run in command prompt, which would be equivalent to a shell script like bash or tcsh).

Contents of 'search_list.txt':

```
grumpy+cat
garfield+cat
basement+cat
```

Contents of 'batch_search.py':

```
# Do a batch bing search in firefox using a keyword search list

# Make import statements
import numpy as np

# Read in the data
keys = np.loadtxt("search_list.txt", dtype='str')

# Output to a batch file
f1=open('./batch_search.bat', 'w+')
for k in keys:
    command = "start firefox http://www.bing.com/search?q="+s+"\r\n"
    f1.write(command)

# Why doesn't this line work?
#%%!batch_search.bat
```

Contents of 'run_batch_search.bat':

```
ipython batch_search.py

batch_search.bat
```

Finally, run in command prompt using:

```
run_batch_search.bat
```

What now?:

The above does open multiple tabs in firefox pointed to the bing search results for the inputed keywords, but I would like this to be a bit more streamlined.

Ideally, I would be able to (most preferably) open the web browsers pointed to the google/bing search directly from the python script. Solutions?

Otherwise, how can I properly format the last line of 'batch_search.py' to get the call to the command prompt to work?

More Information for @Kris (see comments below): The main goal is to look up via web searches hundreds of unknown terms for self education. For example, if I look up [https://www.google.com/search?q=garfield+cat](https://www.google.com/search?q=garfield%20cat) in firefox, the wikipedia results for Garfield cat pops up in the right-hand column of the page. If for one of my own search terms, the Bing popup results appear to be accurate, then I retain that as my reference information and I move on to the results for the next keyword. If it does not appear to be a good match, then I must continue to read the search results and follow links until I find an appropriate match.

Comment: What is the main goal here? Are you trying to extract data from webpages or are you actually trying to open many many browser windows? If it's data you want, you could go the BeautifulSoup way. If you're looking to automate opening webpages in a browser, you could use e.g. Selenium.

Comment: The main goal is to look up via web searches hundreds of unknown terms for self education.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what it is you're trying to accomplish. What is the input, what is the output?

Comment: @Kris The main goal is to look up via web searches hundreds of unknown terms for self education. For example, if I look up [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=garfield+cat) in firefox, the wikipedia results for Garfield cat pops up in the right-hand column of the page. If true with my own search terms, and determined to be accurate (a good match), then I retain that as my reference information and I move on to the results for the next keyword. If it does not appear to be a good match, then I must continue to read the bing results and follow links until I find an appropriate match.

Comment: Okay, well thanks for trying to clarify, but it's still not clear to me what your main goal is. For instance, I don't know what you mean by "if true with my own terms and determined to be accurate". Anyway, I'm sorry but I'm giving up. Good luck!

Comment: The text got garbled after I had to delete characters to be under the 600 mark. Also, editing comments is restricted to a 5 minute window upon pressing enter, so I cannot go back and fix it. If I can I will try editing my original question to clarify my problem and the intended outcome.